# Using Scalacheck with Inside trait

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I have a very simple scenario: test that any pair of random strings of length 10 passed as parameters into a case class Pair(a custom one being under test) should be the same.

```
class ExercisesPropSpec extends PropSpec with Checkers with Matchers with Inside{

  import Exercises._

  lazy val genPairs = for {
    left <- Gen.listOfN(10, Gen.alphaChar)
    right <- Gen.listOfN(10, Gen.alphaChar)
  } yield (left.mkString, right.mkString)

  property("pattern match tuples of alphanumerics to our custom pair class"){
    forAll(genPairs) {case (left: String, right: String) =>
      val pair = Pair(left, right)
      inside(pair) { case Pair(firstName, lastName) =>
        firstName shouldEqual(left)
        lastName shouldEqual(right)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when I am running `testOnly *ExercisesPropSpec` from sbt I get this compilation error:

```
Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/vgorcinschi/ideaProjects/Learning Concurrent Programming in Scala/chapter01_introduction/target/scala-2.12/test-classes ...
[error] ~/ideaProjects/Learning Concurrent Programming in Scala/chapter01_introduction/src/test/scala/org/learningconcurrency/ExercisesPropSpec.scala:18:28: No implicit view available from org.scalatest.Assertion => org.scalacheck.Prop.
[error]     check(forAll(genPairs) {case (left: String, right: String) =>
[error]                            ^
```

[A note](https://github.com/oscarrenalias/scalacheck-cookbook/blob/master/markdown/common-problem-scenarios.md) in scalacheck-cookbook sais that

> what the error message indicates is that our property check is not
>   evaluating in terms of Boolean logic

I was hoping that the inside block in the end should be returning Boolean. I would be grateful if you could point out what am I missing from understanding of property based testing or using [Inside trait](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.Inside) in this implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write

```
firstName == left && lastName == right
```

instead.

(If `shouldEqual` did return `Boolean`, the result of `firstName shouldEqual(left)` would just be discarded.)

Comment: Thank you for your attention Alexey, I replaced two should* lines in the `inside` block with `firstName == left && lastName == right`, unfortunately it yields the same error

Comment: Small correction to my last comment I put `assert(firstName == left && lastName == right)` inside `inside` block

Comment: You don't need the `assert`, do what your first comment says.